# ¿Forma adecuada de iniciar sesion a una pagina web desde una aplicacion android?

Tags: android, http, http-post, http-get

Mi intencion es iniciar sesion desde codigo con el HTTP en una pagina web, y lograr extraer datos una vez dentro de la sesion. El problema es que a decir verdad, soy bastante nuevo en este campo del HTTP... Estuve buscando algunos tutoriales por la web (y navegando tambien aqui entre preguntas) sobre como hacer tal cosa con android.

Encontre algunos videos sobre como capturar las respuestas, y preguntas de algunos usuarios de la comunidad inglesa, en donde mostraban un codigo que por desgracia todas sus clases estan obsoletas (deprecated).

Por ejemplo, [en esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443401/performing-login-to-https-website-via-android-app). Es lo mismo que yo deseo pero como dije antes, si hago uso de ese codigo y me pongo a ver que se hizo en cada linea, sera en vano porque todo me saldra tachado por ser obsoleto.

¿Como entonces podriamos lograr este cometido?

Comment: Buenas, Para empezar necesitaras tener el "login/registro" hecho en php/mysql..etc en una web. Tras verificar que te funciona, entonces deberas hacer peticiones http a traves de android. Tal vez los códigos que encuentras están "obsoletos/deprecated", pero en las formas son correctas. Es decir, puedes buscar,"metodo obsoleto" en android, y muy seguramente encuentres la manera de hacer ese trozo obsoleto con la nueva manera

Comment: Bueno, yo he hecho esto y lo realice de la siguiente manera, primero debes hacer que tu pagina web funcione correctamente (en mi caso use mysql y php) y luego puedes usar un Webview y si explicaras mejor el "extraer datos" te refieres a mostrar solamente en la app los datos de BD, si es asi lo puedes hacer con un Asyntask

Comment: con que Asyntask... ok ok.. bueno y en cuanto a la pagina no es mia, es de mi centro educativo. @Ash :(

Comment: Pero quieres realizar consultas, debes tener acceso a la base de datos